# mysqli insert query not inserting record

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, phpmyadmin

This is my PHP code which is not inserting record and always display **false**.

```
$con = mysqli_connect("localhost", "XXX", "XXX", "vital");
$fieldName = implode(",",array_keys($data));
$values = '"'.implode('","', array_values($data)).'"';

    echo $query = "insert into ".$table." (".$fieldName.") values(".$values.")";
    if(mysqli_query($con,$query))
        echo "<br>true";
    else 
        echo "<br>false";
```

It's equivalent SQL query which I directly write into phpmyadmin which is work perfect. Below SQL query which is generated by `echo $query`

```
insert into patient 
        (patient_id,opd_id,patient_name,hospital_name,plot_from_file,entry_date) 
         values("1234","1233","456","temp","false","2014-08-20");
```

The above query will work perfect in phpmyadmin.

Comment: Don't put unfiltered inputs into the parameters! Use prepared statements!

Comment: I dont know what you mean by `unfiltered inputs`?

Comment: check using mysqli_error()

Comment: I hope you make some checks when you build the $data array.
And yeah an error message could be useful.
+ Why do you use mysqli_query 2 times?

Comment: @Gerifield  sorry It's my mistake for two times write `mysqli_query`

Comment: I write `echo mysqli_error();` but it do not display any error message

Comment: Use prepared statements.

Comment: @hjpotter92 I dont how to use prepared statements but I will try to do that.

Comment: Maybe try to print some error messages like this: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.error.php

Comment: @Gerifield I tried using `echo mysqli_error();` but not display any error message.

Comment: @Sadikhasan exactly `echo mysqli_error();` ? You have to add the db link in the param! So try: `echo mysqli_error($con);`

Comment: @Gerifield I also tried `echo mysqli_error($con);` but not display any error

Comment: Downvoted If you do not have solution then please do not downvote.

Comment: Interesting bug, for now I don't have other ideas. Maybe check the column types and values. (But the type mismatch should generate sql errors...) + Try to rewrite it with prepared statements. That could resolve a lot of problems, maybe this too.

Comment: @Gerifield Thanks for your valuable feedback I will try.

Answer (score -3):

Please try this one

```
  `<?php 
    $con=mysql_connect("localhost","xxx","xxx");
    if(!$con)
   {
   die("could not connect".mysql_error());
   }
   mysql_select_db("DB Name",$con);

   ?>`
    <?php 
   $sql="INSERT INTO patient 
    (patient_id,opd_id,patient_name,hospital_name,plot_from_file,entry_date) 
     values("1234","1233","456","temp","false","2014-08-20"); ?>
```

Comment: I am using mysqli not mysql so please give answer for mysqli

Comment: This is mysqli not mysql.

Comment: For connection database

<?php  
$con = mysqli_connect("myhost","myuser","mypassw","mybd") or die("Error " . mysqli_error($con)); ?>